# Network Diagrams, alternative to Visio

Tags: networking, visio

I often have to give presentations that include extensive use of complex network diagrams to expensive-suit-wearing types. I've always used Visio for network diagrams, but have always felt that they look clunky. What other software is out there which:

1. Can export as HTML with links to other pages.
2. Has some kind of pop-up or menu for object config data (IP-address, OS, License, etc)
3. Looks really sexy.

Comment: Never thought I would see the words "complex networks diagrams" and "expensive-suit-wearing types" on the same sentence. Sorry, couldn't help it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Network Diagramming Software, FREE or Open-Source.](http://serverfault.com/questions/28085/network-diagramming-software-free-or-open-source)

Comment: For the record, I voted to close this a dupe, not as off-topic. I really can't see why others voted for off-topic.

Answer (score 7):

[OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) for Mac is great for just kind of thing, have you considered using VisioCafe's excellent make/model-specific stencils with Visio? - actually having representative graphics of the actual servers/switches etc. adds so much.

Answer (score 3):

OSAlt has a decent list of open source alternatives to Visio

http://www.osalt.com/visio

Answer (score 2):

I've been teaching myself [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) for this purpose(amongst others) the investment is going to be a bit higher to start with

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. I think I'll stick with Visio for now, using some of the great templates at Visio Cafe.

Comment: I love graphviz. The nice thing about the DOT language is that it's a relatively mild learning curve and it's easy to write programs to output graphs using any programming language.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia) and [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org) for UML models. However, I've found that Visio tends to be the shortest path from scratch to polished diagram. Especially when using templates and shapes from [VisioCafe](http://visiocafe.com).

Answer (score 1):

yED is a free (but not open source) Java application. It can export diagrams in formats such as >

html, jpg, pdf, png, svg, swf

It also includes a good library of diagram elements.

More info including a 90 second video of it in action here >
[yED Graph Editor](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html)

Answer (score 1):

[draw.io](http://www.draw.io), it has a function to create a JavaScript embedded version of the diagram, that is pannable, linkable and scalable (it's vector, no bitmap scaling problems).